# How to execute query on a large database without exists

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, join, subquery

MYSQL 5.1.52-community
i have a big table with 2.5 millions rows:

i wrote this query to parse data :

```sql
SELECT dem.iddem,
       rrbc.p0012 AS libdemandeur,
       rrbp.p0012 AS libaffectation,
       dem.regate,
       dem.bp,
       dem.typeabsence,
       dem.datedeb,
       dem.datefin
FROM   demandes dem
       LEFT OUTER JOIN regate_regate rrbp
                    ON rrbp.p0016 = '038'
                       AND dem.bp = rrbp.regate
       LEFT OUTER JOIN regate_regate rrbc
                    ON ( rrbc.p0016 = '038'
                         AND dem.regate = rrbc.regate )
       INNER JOIN planning_demandes pd
               ON dem.iddem = pd.id_dem
WHERE  1
       AND EXISTS(SELECT 1
                  FROM   planning_demandes b
                  WHERE  pd.id_dem = b.id_dem
                         AND idrh IS NOT NULL
                         AND idrh <> 'férié'
                         AND idrh <> 'Pferié')
       AND EXISTS(SELECT 1
                  FROM   planning_demandes c
                  WHERE  pd.id_dem = c.id_dem
                         AND idrh IS NULL)
       AND dem.etat NOT IN ( '0', '1', '2', '7', '8' )
GROUP  BY iddem
ORDER  BY dem.datedeb ASC
```

i would like to know if someone has idea to fast load this request :

maybe subqueries are a really bad idea on big table ?
i created this index : create index IDX_DEM_IDRH on planning_demandes(id_dem, idrh);

[EXPLAIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdD9y.png)

[INDEX OF PLANNING_DEMANDES AND DEMANDES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvdWs.png)

Comment: which of these tables have 2.5 million rows?what is the volume of other tables? I would call 2.5 million rows 'moderate' - depends on the number of columns though

Comment: Query execution : 91.8204 sec

table demandes : 149267 rows
table planning_demandes : 2545088 rows
table regate_regate : 20650 rows

Comment: Not related to your question, but the information "MySQL 5" isn't really very informative. There is 5.0, 5.1, 5.5, 5.6, 5.7 (and various patch releases for each of them - each patch release with different functionality and features)

Comment: yes sorry its MYSQL 5.1.52-community

Comment: Your `EXISTS` clause can likely be combined (conditions appear to be `OR`-able).  Note that if there are multiple rows in `regate_regate` with matching criteria, the result value in `p0012` is undefined (due to `GROUP BY` with no aggregates) - and this is assuming `demandes.idem` is unique to begin with (do you need the `GROUP BY` at all?).  I personally dislike this "feature".

Comment: i dont really needs the GROUP BY, but i need to returns same results, how can i rewrite this request?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the explain plan for this query and verify if it is using the index IDX_DEM_IDRH or not. Also check which join is taking the maximum time.

Syntax:

```
explain plan for <your select query>;
select * from table(dbms_xplan);
```

I think you should have separate indexes on planning_demandes.id_dem and planning_demandes.idrh. Also consider a index on demandes.iddem.

Comment: you look on the right way ? is there any problems with my explain ?

Comment: Well I am a Oracle guy.. (sorry for missing the MySQL tag)
Anyways.. looking at the plan its obvious that the query's bottleneck is the full table scan of "demandes"

Comment: sorry, but i dont understand . in another way should i not replace subqueries by join ?

Comment: yr subqueries seem to be fine.. as you can see in your explain plan, the dependent queries are doing fine, they are using index and effectively doing just 5 and 8 row searches

Comment: yes but tables "demandes" have 100k row searches should i create temporary table or ?

Comment: You can tray creating a staging/intermediate table and load the relevent data from demandes into that table first. Then execute this query from this new table.
Basically you need  a new table(say "demandes_stg") of same structure as demades. Then populate demandes_stg from demades first with only the rows which meet the following criteria:
demades.etat NOT IN ( '0', '1', '2', '7', '8' )
demades.iddem = pd.id_dem

Then create all the indexes on demandes_stg as well. Execute the above query on demandes_stg and check the timing